# tabularcolumns directive in an admonition is not shown in latex

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, directive

I'm using sphinx for my documentation. 
I have a note admonition in which I want to add a table. Since I want to have the table be spread over the whole width of the note, i want to use the tabularcolumns directive.
However when adding this directive, the table is not rendered to latex format and as such not to pdf or html.

This is my restructured text snippet:

```
.. note:: 

   Reserve the necessary amount of time to install your environment. The following table gives approximate values for installation of the Operating System (OS) and for the initialization of the nodes.

   .. tabularcolumns:: |p{5cm}|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|

   +-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
   | Node                    | Install OS (parallel) | Initialize (serial) |
   +=========================+=======================+=====================+
   | AS20/AS30 Storage Node  | 12 minutes            | 10 minutes          |
   +-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
   | AS36 Storage Node       | 8 minutes             | 15 minutes          |
   +-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
   | AC1/AC2 Controller Node | 8 minutes             | 15 minutes          |
   +-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

When I omit the directive, the table is correctly processed

Answer (score -1):

If you indent the table 3 spaces, it should work. Like this:

```
.. note:: 

   Reserve the necessary amount of time to install your environment. The
   following table gives approximate values for installation of the 
   Operating System (OS) and for the initialization of the nodes.

   .. tabularcolumns:: |p{5cm}|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|

      +-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
      | Node                    | Install OS (parallel) | Initialize (serial) |
      +=========================+=======================+=====================+
      | AS20/AS30 Storage Node  | 12 minutes            | 10 minutes          |
      +-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
      | AS36 Storage Node       | 8 minutes             | 15 minutes          |
      +-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
      | AC1/AC2 Controller Node | 8 minutes             | 15 minutes          |
      +-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
```